# Laravel: Migration & Seeding Problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to seed a database and am getting an error when I run `php artisan migrate:fresh`:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `news` add constraint `news_author_id_foreign` foreign key (`author_id`) references `authors` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at C:\laragon\www\startup-reporter\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  1   C:\laragon\www\startup-reporter\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")

  2   C:\laragon\www\startup-reporter\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Here are the migration files:

```
Schema::create('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
   ...
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
  $table->foreign('author_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('authors')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

```
Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And here are the factory files:

```
$factory->define(Author::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name
    ];
});
```

```
    return [
      ...
      'author_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 50),
    ];
```

And finally, here are the seed files:

```
// DatabaseSeeder
    {
        $this->call(AuthorsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(NewsTableSeeder::class);
    }

// NewsSeeder and AuthorSeeder

factory(App\News::class, 150)->create();
factory(App\Authors::class, 50)->create();
```

Any idea why I am getting this error and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply because the migration file for `news` runs before `authors`

just try to change the timestamp for these two files to make `authors` migration run before `news` migration

Comment: How do I do that?  I am semi-new to Laravel.  Also, in my DatabaseSeeder file, `authors` comes before `news` (I'll update my question to show that.

Comment: I mean in the migrations folder
when you create a new migration file it comes with a timestamp like this:
`2020_03_26_152343_create_news_table.php`
just make sure that the timestamp in `authors` file is before the news `file`

Comment: because Laravel runs the migration file with its order, so when you run the `news` migration file it is looking for a table named `author`, and it couldn't find it, so it throws an exception... that's it